# Referencing ZXing.Net library

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to reference the ZXing library to scan QR codes in my Windows Phone 8 app.
I have downloaded the ZXing.Net 0.10.0.0 from the following source: http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

However, whenever i try to add a reference to  zxing.wp8.0.dll, I get an error as follows:

> A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added
>   to the project.

Can I please know why am I getting this error. Is there anything that I am doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Right click on the DLL in File Explorer --> Click Properties --> Choose unblock. Then try to add a reference again.

VS2012 has the absolute worst error message for when DLLs are blocked due to the fact they were downloaded from the web.

Comment: you are a legend, you saved me from re-writing an entire library!

Answer (score 0):

Goto 
http://nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net

Follow the instructions to install the right version you need.