# Windows phone 8 App with 7.1 reference

Tags: windows-phone-7, reference, visual-studio-2012, compatibility, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referencing ZXing.Net library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698094/referencing-zxing-net-library)

I'm developing an application that targetting Windows phone 8.0 OS
When I try to add a reference of version (7.1) to the application ,

it gives the following error message:

> A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be
>   added to the project

Why?

Comment: Can be a number of reasons. Is it a third party DLL you just downloaded or something "built in" to the SDKs?

Comment: I've created this DLL previously

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the answer to this question at a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698737/81687). This isn't an issue with "higher version", just VS2012 having an irrelevant error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's proper WP7.1 assembly, because for me it works just fine.
Make sure it's not built against WP7.0, it must be for WP7.1 - try to rebuild this assembly in VS2012, and also you cannot reference XNA libraries as far as I know.