# silverlight toolkit (microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit ) issue

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have been devolping  a windows 8 application since last 2 months. It has been working fine, but today i got an error saying "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project" the time i was trying to add microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit (august 2011 windows phone silverlight toolkit) to my project. I had the same toolkit added to my project before but I had to remove toolkit because of some reasons. The same toolkit was working fine before,but now i am facing this problem. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing via [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit)

> Install-Package WPtoolkit

This will guarantee you have the latest version consistent to your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer to this question at a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698737/81687). This isn't an issue with "higher version", just VS2012 having an irrelevant error message.