# Add references to my WP8 C# project

Tags: reference, windows-phone-8, azure-storage, visual-studio-express

I want to add references, like windowsazure.storage to my WP8 C# project, but i keep getting this error:

> A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added
>   to the project

How to fix this? I've tried upgrading the nuget, and have unblocked the file but i still get the same error.

Comment: I found the answer in [This post][1], hope that will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13698737/81687

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that I hope it can help you. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Using-Windows-Azure-Storage-on-Windows-Phone

I also found a solution for this in similar issues related to Windows Azure and Windows Phone in the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/7f4dea12-4960-4112-a360-dde78aa2e6ed