# Connecting Oracle database with C#

Tags: c#, database, windows, visual-studio

While adding reference to a dll file called `oracleDataAccess.dll` to my project I get an error.

> A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be
>   added to the project.

I have the code for connecting c# with oracle which I got from this site.

Help me out to solve this problem.  I am using visual studio ultimate 2012.

Comment: Doesn't the error is pretty clear? Your current project is targeting lower version of framework, but your reference assembly is built in higher version. Which doesn't makes sense.!

Comment: what should I do for this?

Comment: Either you should make your current project to target higher framework version or target the `oracleDataAccess.dll` to lower framework version and rebuild it, then add it to reference

Comment: I tried changing the framework to higher version but didn't work

Comment: You forgot to reference the link to "this site".

Comment: What was the version of both projects earlier and now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing ZXing.Net library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698094/referencing-zxing-net-library)

Comment: earlier version 2.0 and now 4.5@SriramSakthivel

Comment: It should work. If not try @Coder's solution

Comment: Even that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Change your version to the higher framework, rigth click on your project, change the framework, fix the references and recompile. If you have dependencies, first do the dependencies. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Data Access Components are very specific to which versions of .NET they use.  Since you're using a newer version of Visual Studio/.NET, did you try getting an updated version of the ODAC tools?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html