# SharpZipLib issue while adding reference Windows Phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add dll of `SharpZipLib` to my `Windows Phone 8` project. It gives me following error while adding

> a reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project

Here is a **screen shot**

[image: Error]

I found one same type of question. [Referencing ZXing.Net library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698094/referencing-zxing-net-library/13698737#13698737)
But it not works in my case. I have downloaded this dll from http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx

Can some one please help me ? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Microsoft Compression](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression/) library on NuGet instead? It definitely lists support for Windows Phone 8.

If that's not an option for you, try to add the [SharpZipLib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/) package via NuGet as it will have clearer messaging if the package does not support WP8.

Comment: Getting this error : `Could not install package 'SharpZipLib 0.86.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.`

Comment: @Ajay - Sounds like SharpZipLib definitely doesn't support WP8. I'd recommend using the Microsoft Compression library. It supports both HTTP Gzip and Zip archives and definitely supports WP8.

Comment: I have also check this `Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Compression`, but it also give an error `Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Compression 3.9.69'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, 
contact the package author.`

Comment: Can I extract zip file of images by using Microsoft Compression Library

Comment: @Ajay - Yes to the zip of images question. Not sure about the error, though. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/22/portable-compression-is-now-stable.aspx) explicitly mentions WP8 as a supported platform.

Comment: Yeah but I don't know why this error I am getting, while running the command from **Package Manager Console**

Answer (score 0):

The binary you downloaded is for full .NET Framework projects only. If you want to use it in Windows Phone projects, you need to download the source code and rip out parts that are not Windows Phone friendly.

Note that SharpZipLib does not officially support Windows Phone, so you might have to fight hard to port it to Windows Phone.

Thus, you'd better use a library that officially supports Windows Phone, such as SharpCompress,

https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Ajay, do you have difficulty reading what I answered? SharpCompress is obviously another way. If in fact you want to evaluate all possible options, instead of using one of them, you will have to do your own research and I will vote for this question to be closed.